# lambda function of another function but force fixed argument

Tags: python, function, lambda

I just switched to Python from Matlab, and I want to use lambda function to map function `f1(x,y)` with multiple arguments to one argument function `f2(x)` for optimization. 
I want that when I map the function `f2(x) <- f1(x,y=y1)` then `y` will stay constant no matter what `y1` changes, in Matlab this is true by default but if I try in Python, it keeps changing as the following examples

```
>>> def f1(x,y):
>>>    return (x+y)
>>> y1 = 2
>>> f2 = lambda x: f1(x,y1)
>>> f2(1)
3
```

I expect `f2(1)` stays `3` even if I change `y1`, however if I change `y1`, the whole `f1(1)` also changes as follows

```
>>> y1 = 5
>>> f2(1)
6
```

I wonder is there a way that when I declare `f2 = lambda x: f1(x,y1)` then `f1` will take the value of `y1` at that time and fix it to `f2`. The reason for this because I want to dynamically create different functions for different scenarios then sum them all.
I'm still new to Python, please help, much appreciate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
f2 = lambda x, y=y1: f1(x,y)
```

Your issue has to do with [how closures work in Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Your version of the lambda function will use the current version of `y1`.  You need to *capture* the value of `y1` on the line where you've defined the lambda function.  To do that, you can define it as the default value of a parameter (the `y=y1` part).

Comment: it now works as I want, thanks for the tip, I feel like it is kinda a trick as `f2` actually still has two arguments, but it also takes 1 argument hence works for my case

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, your issue comes down to how closures work. However, you really shouldn't be using a lambda for this - lambdas are for anonymous functions. Make a higher-order function with `def` statements instead:

```
>>> def f1(x,y):
...   return x + y
... 
>>> def f1_factory(y):
...   def f1_y(x):
...     return f1(x,y)
...   return f1_y
... 
>>> f1_factory(6)(4)
10
>>> f1_factory(5)(4)
9
```

It also avoids the problem you encountered:

```
>>> y = 3
>>> newfunc = f1_factory(y)
>>> newfunc(1)
4
>>> y = 20
>>> newfunc(1)
4
>>>
```

From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
>   binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> def f(x): return 2*x
>
> No:
>
> f = lambda x: 2*x
>
> The first form means that the name of the resulting
>   function object is specifically 'f' instead of the generic `<lambda>`.
>   This is more useful for tracebacks and string representations in
>   general. The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole
>   benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement
>   (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression)

Comment: I always use @ function in Matlab, I thought lambda function in Python is exactly same thing. I will keep this in mind for future coding, thanks a lot for the advice

Comment: @JoseVu It's more a matter of style, really. Both of these are anonymous functions. But the style in Python is that if your anonymous function isn't going to be, well, anonymous, then just use a full function definition statement.